# How to prevent text from overflowing in CSS?

Tags: html, css, overflow

How can I prevent text in a div block from overflowing in CSS?

```css
div {
  width: 150px;
  /* what to put here? */
}
```

```html
<div>This div contains a VeryLongWordWhichDoesNotFitToTheBorder.</div>
```

Comment: why is your text overflowing?

Comment: @ViratKadaru ...because it's 360pt Gregorian Chant Serif

Answer (score 219):

If you want the overflowing text in the div to automatically newline instead of being hidden or making a scrollbar, use the

`word-wrap: break-word`

property.

Comment: [https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/word-wrap](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/word-wrap)

Comment: The user needs to check this as the answer. It worked for me today! Thanks pal!

Comment: oh my goodness thank you so much for this one, i've been literally gone crazy bc of some problems that I could solve by your answer!! XD

Comment: It's now word-break: break-all

Answer (score 90):

## Short Answer

Simply use:

```
word-wrap: break-word;
white-space: pre-wrap;
word-break: break-word;
```

## Long Answer

### 1. `word-wrap`

Allows long words to be able to break and wrap onto the next line.

**Possible values:**

- `normal`: Break words only at allowed break points
- `break-word`: Allows unbreakable words to be broken

```css
div {
    width: 150px; 
    border: 2px solid #ff0000;
}

div.normal {
    word-wrap: normal;
}

div.break {
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

```html
<h2>word-wrap: normal</h2>
<div class="normal"> This div contains a VeryLongWordWhichDoesNotFitToTheBorder.</div>

<h2>word-wrap: break-word</h2>
<div class="break"> This div contains a VeryLongWordWhichDoesNotFitToTheBorder.</div>
```

### 2. `white-space`

Specifies how white-space inside an element is handled.

**Possible values:**

- `nowrap`: Text will never wrap to the next line.
- `pre-wrap`: Whitespace is preserved by the browser. Text will wrap when necessary, and on line breaks

```css
div {
    width: 150px;
    border: 2px solid #ff0000;
}

div.nowrap {
    white-space: nowrap;
}

div.pre-wrap {
    white-space: pre-wrap;
}
```

```html
<h2>white-space: nowrap</h2>
<div class="nowrap">This div contains a very long but normal paragraph with so many words and nothing else.</div>

<h2>white-space: pre-wrap</h2>
<div class="pre-wrap">This div contains a very long but normal paragraph with so many words and nothing else.</div>
```

### 3. `word-break`

Specifies how words should break when reaching the end of a line.

**Possible values:**

- `normal`: default line break rules.
- `break-word`: To prevent overflow, word may be broken at arbitrary points.

```css
div {
  width: 150px; 
  border: 2px solid #ff0000;
}

div.normal {
  word-break: normal;
}

div.break-word {
  word-break: break-word;
}
```

```html
<h2>word-break: normal (default)</h2>
<div class="normal"> This div contains a VeryLongWordWhichDoesNotFitToTheBorder.</div>

<h2>word-break: break-word</h2>
<div class="break-word"> This div contains a VeryLongWordWhichDoesNotFitToTheBorder.</div>
```

For browser-specific versions of `white-space`, use:

```
white-space: pre-wrap;      /* CSS3 */
white-space: -moz-pre-wrap; /* Firefox */
white-space: -pre-wrap;     /* Opera <7 */
white-space: -o-pre-wrap;   /* Opera 7 */
```

Comment: Almost 8 years of this great answer not being the accepted one.

Comment: In my case `white-space: pre-wrap;` is the only thing that made the overflowing text break for me. Thank you!

Answer (score 89):

You can try:

```
<div id="myDiv">
    stuff 
</div>

#myDiv {
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

Check out [the docs for the overflow property](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_overflow.asp) for more information.

Comment: Those aren't "the docs", that's a web site with some basic information about HTML/CSS. The docs are at w3.org

Answer (score 63):

You can use the CSS property text-overflow to truncate long texts.

```css
  #greetings
  {
    width: 100px;
    border: 1px red solid;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis; // This is where the magic happens
  }
```

```html
    <div id="greetings">
      Hello universe! 
    </div>

    <div id="greetings">
      Hello universe! 12345678901234567890
    </div>
```

reference:
http://makandracards.com/makandra/5883-use-css-text-overflow-to-truncate-long-texts

Answer (score 20):

You can control it with CSS, there is a few options :

- hidden -> All text overflowing will be hidden.
- visible -> Let the text overflowing visible.
- scroll -> put scroll bars if the text overflows

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 15):

there is another css property :

```
white-space : normal;
```

The white-space property controls how text is handled on the element it is applied to.

```
div {

  /* This is the default, you don't need to
     explicitly declare it unless overriding
     another declaration */
  white-space: normal; 

}
```

Comment: This is really helpful in combination with overflow:hidden;

Answer (score 6):

Try adding this class in order to fix the issue:

```
.ellipsis {
  text-overflow: ellipsis;

  /* Required for text-overflow to do anything */
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Explained further in this link http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/t/text-overflow/

Answer (score 5):

`overflow: scroll` ? Or auto. 
in the style attribute.

Answer (score 5):

I guess you should start with the basics from w3

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_text-overflow.asp

```
div {
    white-space: nowrap; 
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

Comment: See [this link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-overflow#examples) for an example from MDN

Answer (score 5):

It's now the css property:

> `word-break: break-all`

Answer (score 2):

```css
.NonOverflow {
    width: 200px; /* Need the width for this to work */
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="NonOverflow">
    Long Text
</div>
```

Comment: in multilingual text other than, it causes some characters of long words be hidden from display.

Answer (score 1):

If your div has a set height in css that will cause it to overflow outside of the div.

You could give the div a min-height if you need to have it be a minimum height on the div at all times.

Min-height will not work in IE6 though, if you have an IE6 specific stylesheet you can give it a regular height for IE6. Height changes in IE6 according to the content within.

Answer (score 1):

You can just set the min-width in the css, for example:

```
.someClass{min-width: 980px;}
```

It will not break, nevertheless you will still have the scroll-bar to deal with.

Answer (score 1):

Recommendations for how to catch which part of your CSS is causing the issue:

1) set `style="height:auto;"` on all the `<div>` elements and retry again.

2) Set `style="border: 3px solid red;"` on all the `<div>` elements to see how wide of an area your `<div>`'s box is taking up.

3) Take away all the css `height:#px;` properties from your CSS and start over.

So for example:

```
<div id="I" style="height:auto;border: 3px solid red;">I
    <div id="A" style="height:auto;border: 3px solid purple;">A
        <div id="1A" style="height:auto;border: 3px solid green;">1A
        </div>
        <div id="2A" style="height:auto;border: 3px solid green;">2A
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="B" style="height:auto;border: 3px solid purple;">B
        <div id="1B" style="height:auto;border: 3px solid green;">1B
        </div>
        <div id="2B" style="height:auto;border: 3px solid green;">2B
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

*!! **Hard coded** tradoff ahead !! Depending on the surrounding code and the screen resolution this could lead to different / unwanted behaviour*

If hidden overflow is out of the question and correct hyphenation is needed you could use the soft hyphen HTML entity where you want the word / text to break. This way you are able to predetermine a breaking point manually.

```
&shy;
```

The hyphen will only appear when the word needs to break to not overflow its surrounding container.

Example:

```
<div class="container">
  foo&shy;bar
</div>
```

Result if the container is wide enough and the text would not overflow the container:

```
foobar
```

Result if the container is to small and the text would actually overflow the container:

```
foo-
bar
```

```css
.container{
  background-color: green;
  max-width: 30px;
}
```

```html
Example 1 - container to small => text overflows container:

<div class="container">
  foobar
</div>

Example 2 - using soft hyphen => text breaks at predetermined break point:

<div class="container">
  foo&shy;bar
</div>

Example 3 - using soft hyphen => text still overflowing because the text before the soft hyphen is to long:

<div class="container">
  foobar&shy;foo
</div>
```

Further information: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soft_hyphen