# Text outside framework how to solve with css?

Tags: css

I'm new to CSS and I was wondering if there was a sollution to get my text inside the framework on a mobile device.

This is my .css:

```
.post-details .post-entry > p {
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
}
```

Comment: Seems related to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1165497/can-i-prevent-text-in-a-div-block-from-overflowing

Comment: Apply this `word-wrap: break-word;`

Comment: Please post code and not pictures of code - my firewall blocks imigur and thus this question makes no sense without the actual code - see how to create a [mcve].  If you do not post enough code in the question to replicate your error, this question is off-topic:Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the Word Wrap CSS property?

```
.post-details .post-entry > p {
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

Ref: https://www.w3schools.com/csSref/css3_pr_word-wrap.asp