# Why is the containing content overlapping it's DIV?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to build a regular calculator but the layout doesn't behave. The "div.row div" css selector is being overlapped by its containing content to the right side. I tried checking chrome dev tools, but margin, padding and border are set to 0, so it doesn't give me a reason why it's happening.

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  width: 40%;
  height: 1000px;
  max-width: 1000px;
  min-width: 250px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
main {
  padding: 3%;
  background-color: #753471;
}
div.row div {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 16.25%;
  height: 30px;
  padding: 2%;
  background-color: #f2d8f0;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0.3%;
  font-size: 85%;
}
div.row {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0%;
  padding: 0;
}
div#output {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
  <title>Calculator</title>
</head>
<body>
  <header></header>
  <main>
    <!-- output -->
    <div id="output"></div>

  <div class="row">
    <div id="clear">C</div>
    <div id="mudulu">%</div>
    <div id="division">÷</div>
    <div id="times">x</div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div id="one">1</div>
    <div id="two">2</div>
    <div id="three">3</div>
    <div id="minus">-</div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div id="four">4</div>
    <div id="five">5</div>
    <div id="six">6</div>
    <div id="plus">+</div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div id="seven">7</div>
    <div id="eight">8</div>
    <div id="nine">9</div>
    <div id="equals">=</div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div id="decimal">.</div>
    <div id="zero">0</div>
    <div id="delete">backspace</div>
  </div>
  </main>
  
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You're limiting the width `width: 16.25%;`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to prevent text from overflowing in CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1165497/how-to-prevent-text-from-overflowing-in-css)

Comment: @ZohirSalak Thanks! I changed it & it's working.