# Text is overflowed even i use substring to truncate the string in JS

Tags: javascript, css, truncate

I have string which I truncate to fit in the card but when there is white space in the text it fit perfectly but when white space is not present it just overflow  [Just like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LdAmC.png)

My code for truncate look like this

```
function truncateString(string, maxLength) {
      console.log(`${string.length} and ${maxLength}`)
      return string.substring(0, maxLength) + "...";
}
```

What can be the reason?
What can be an alternative?

And when I use text-overflow in CSS it will not cover height
[just like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rUPx9.png)

My HTML code look

```
<div class="dateDiv">
  <p class="infoTxt">${noteObj.date}</p>
</div>
<div class="titleDiv">
  <p class="title">${truncateString(noteObj.title,15)}</p>
</div>
<div class="contentDiv">
  <p class="regularTxt">${truncateString(noteObj.note,188)}</p>
</div>
<div class="authorDiv">
  <p class="infoTxt">${noteObj.author}</p>
</div>
<i class="delBtn fas fa-trash-alt fa-lg"></i>
<div class="noteOverlay"></div>
```

Comment: Don't do this in JavaScript, use css https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/t/text-overflow/

Comment: Please share the HTML

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to prevent text from overflowing in CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1165497/how-to-prevent-text-from-overflowing-in-css)

Comment: When I use text -overflow in CSS it will not cover total height with text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the regular text class, add following CSS property

```
regularTxt {
 ...

 word-break: break-all;
}
```