# Websites sidebar content going off the sidebar

Tags: html, css, sidebar

this is whats happening (the sidebar goes on the right I just put it there to visualise the problem
[screenshot of website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eGK8Q.png)

so how would I stop this happening here is the CSS and HTML code below

HTML

```
<div class="sidebar">
    aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaabbbbbbbbaaaaaaaaaaaa
  </div>
  <footer>Copyright &#169; Hot Beans 2028</footer>
</html>
```

CSS

```
.sidebar {
    background: rgb(5,68,104);
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 20%;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 20px 0;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can use word-wrap

```
word-wrap: break-word;
```

Like this

https://stackoverflow.com/a/23842462/17177726